# Safari URL to PDF-page workaround?

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, safari, paging

I'm trying to link from an URL to a specific page within a PDF document being viewed using the Preview.app built in Safari (using iOS on iPad2).
I know that Sarafi does not support (hopefully in the near future) the PDF parameters like for example:

> www.mywebsite.com/information.pdf#page17

or

> www.mywebsite.com/information.pdf#page=17

Which should result in the PDF being viewed on page 17 when opened.
But as we know Safari opens it at the first page instead.

However!

When I am displaying the PDF in Safari and I change the pagenumber (in the URL bar) into a different pagenumber, IT WORKS. 
It jumps to the correct page, and I'm changing it again and again and it works flawlessly.

So I figured, alright maybe it's because the PDF needs to be loaded the first time viewing, so I preloaded the PDF in cache, but no succes.

How can I get it to work, so that it goes to the correct page when opening the PDF?
Is there a script for changing the page number after loading or is there a different solution?

You can find the PDF I'm talking about here:
http://www.michaelmaasdam.nl/mobile/new/pagina/begroting/begroting2012.pdf?page=14

Answer (score 0):

Is this link being shown from a native app?

If so, you could opt to use [QuickLook](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDwQFjAC&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/quicklook_programming_guide/&ei=T97AUsnaAZH6oAT8loH4AQ&usg=AFQjCNFPMSN7tF43SfNIaM5m9a-sYq6CTw&sig2=4Mh_yz5NjaeJy_OglL0SGw&bvm=bv.58187178,d.cGU) instead and you may have a little more control over this kind of thing from within that.